# Conditional Callbacks Execution : What would be an elegant way to solve it?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I have created an almost unreadable code like this with different MongoDB queries. There is a high chance you can't make it till the end.

```
Collection1.find({}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    else if (doc) {
        Collection2.find({}, (err, doc) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            else if (doc) {
                let cursor = Collection3.find({})
                cursor.exec((err, doc) => {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    else if (doc) {
                        Collection4.find();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                var y = new Collection2({
                    x: "S",
                    y: "D"
                })
                y.save((err, doc) => {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    else if (doc) {
                        Collection3.find({});
                        let cursor = Collection3.find({})
                        cursor.exec((err, doc) => {
                            if (err)
                                throw err;
                            else if (doc) {
                                Collection4.find();
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    } else {
        taskComplete();
    }
})
```

Now one solution to the callback hell problem is that I break those anonymous function as **named function**.That might solve some problem but I think we can do better than that.
I also thought about **async.series, async.waterfall**... Somehow I feel they don't fit the bill as it's not like I need to get this task done post this. It's more like if this than that which is not supported by both of these. I cannot choose which task to run based on conditions.
Which leaves me with **promises and generators**. 
Well, those DB calls are promises in itself. But how to integrate that with if and else is something I don't have experience with. I was hoping that more experienced JavaScript out here on SO could help me out with this and give me some guidelines on how to handle this issue more gracefully.

Edit I haven't really given a thought to generators. But would they help if included?

Comment: `those db calls are promises in itself` - yet no .then in sight!!

Comment: There is not only one way to write promises... People have created wrappers over the barebone library like this one [here](https://promisesaplus.com/).

Comment: You can also have a look on mongoose.js docs to see how they have done it. [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

Comment: Of course you can have Promises fully encapsulated in some API - but if they aren't exposed then you can't "integrate that"

Comment: So you mean to say it's not possible? I mean a promise-like solution to this problem.

Comment: I didn't say that either - but because I don't know anything about the "promises" that apparently "exist" in the code, I can't actually supply an answer - my comment was simply a remark that there doesn't seem to be any promises in the code as presented - because there are none evident

Comment: The task at hand isn't clear. You have a lot of code here that doesn't do anything observable. What is this code trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: See the task of the code is trivial. In plain english, If I find values in Collection1 do task 1. else do task 2. Task 1 is Searching in Collection2.find(). if I find the item then Search in collection3 else create an element in Collection2. The point I wanted to make is. These are DB calls based on conditions. If I wanted to write a clean code, say a readable code. How would you re write that...